# ¿Por qué mi web se ve mal en iphone?

Tags: android, css, iphone, mediaqueries, font-faces

Tengo la siguiente página: `https://nej92.github.io/NGE/` y el problema que en iphone, se ve mal. En PC y celulares android de distintas marcas se ve bien, pero cuando lo miran en un iphone parece ser que no toma algunas propiedades del CSS, así como tampoco toma las fuentes.

Las fuentes están agregadas de esta manera:

```
@font-face{

font-family: "Poppins";

src: url('/Poppins/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf'),

url('/Poppins/Poppins/Poppins-BoldItalic.ttf');

}
```

También probé exportarlas desde Google Fonts, pero me pasa lo mismo (en iphone).

¿Cómo se puede resolver esto?

Answer (score 0):

Las fuentes `ttf` no funcionan en Safari. Debes declarar la fuente en multiples tipos de la siguiente manera:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'miFuente';
  src: url('miFuente.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url('miFuente.woff') format('woff'), 
   url('miFuente.ttf')  format('truetype'),
   url('miFuente.svg#nombreFuenteSvg') format('svg');
}
```

Puedes usar el [generador de fuentes de FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) para convertir a `eot`, `woff` y `svg`. Sube tu fuente, selecciona la opción 'EXPERT' y marca los tipos de fuente que quieras.